# Can't use renewenvironment minipage for first word hyphenation

Tags: tables, environments, longtable, minipage

I have a bunch of tables, some of them have many columns. Since latex doesn't hyphenate the first word, the texts in my table cells sometimes exceed the boundary of tables. Something like this:

[image: table]

This is what my tables look like in latex, longtables with minipages.

```
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\columnwidth}\raggedright
Col1\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Col2\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright
Col3\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
Col4\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.15\columnwidth}\raggedright
Col5\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.07\columnwidth}\raggedright
Col6\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.19\columnwidth}\raggedright
preoccupation\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
inappropriate\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright
responsibility\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.11\columnwidth}\raggedright
consciousness\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\columnwidth}\raggedright
preoccupation\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.07\columnwidth}\raggedright
infrastructure\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

I know that putting an \hspace{0pt} before the first word will give me what I want, so I tried to redefine the minipage environment. Like this:

```
\let\oldminipage\minipage
\let\endoldminipage\endminipage
\renewenvironment{minipage}{
\oldminipage \hspace{0pt} }{
\endoldminipage}
```

With this piece of code, I'm getting this error:

```
[3] [4]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.597 \begin{minipage}
                      [b]{0.19\columnwidth}\raggedright
?
```

Any idea why this is not working? Isn't this possible?

Comment: Why are you using minipage instead of p or b column type?

Comment: I'm not using it myself, they are converted from markdown with pandoc

Comment: Then sent a bug report to pandoc. This looks quite silly. (And spacing will probably be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Since latex doesn't hyphenate the first word [of a paragraph, of a table cell] ...

I can think of two remedies:

- If you're free to use LuaLaTeX, the constraint that the first word of a paragraph/table cell won't get hyphenated is no longer present.
- If you must use either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX, be sure to load the `array` package (or a package, such as `tabularx`, which loads `array` automatically) and to augment the column type from `p{2in}` to `>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2in}`, `X` to  `>{\hspace{0pt}}X`, etc. That way, the first "word" of the cell is the invisible item "\hspace{0pt}", and any subsequent word is no longer the "first" word.

[image]

not a `minipage` in sight ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % note "\hspace{0pt}" item

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} *{4}{p{1cm}} @{}}
\toprule
Preoccupation & Inappropriate & Responsibility & Consciousness \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} *{4}{C{1cm}} @{}}
\toprule
Preoccupation & Inappropriate & Responsibility & Consciousness \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but I am not able to change the table structure since the pdf documents are generated with pandoc. I need to fix it  in the preamble(in pandoc's latex template) while keeping the tables with minipages.

Comment: @MertcanSeğmen - The `\hspace{{0pt}` trick works with `minipage` environments as well.  Incidentally, I can only recommend that you  try very hard not to use the awful template you've been given.